# Build gcc with a different name

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make, open-source, gnu

I am new to gcc and I'm trying to modify the source code of either *gcc* or *arm-none-eabi-gcc* in order to rename the compiler in the codebase to something like *myCompiler*. This adjustment would enable commands such as `myCompiler --version` to be recognized.

I understand that using symbolic links offers a workaround, but it doesn't involve modifying the source code directly. I am specifically interested in altering the source code and renaming `gcc` to `myCompiler`.

I've downloaded the source code for both *gcc* and *arm-none-eabi-gcc*, but I'm uncertain how to proceed. I'm unable to locate main files such as gcc.c or main.c that I could play around with. Any guidance on how to begin would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The steps I would take: follow their build instructions to 'configure' and 'make' the compiler. Once it's built, look at the 'Makefile'. Somewhere in there is the filename of the final product. You can change that. HTH.